# I want to make an app in flutter. Can following features be implemented in android and iOS related to call?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

1. If any unknown number call on my phone, the phone should not ring usually it will when contact is saved.
2. Can the unknown call be picked in background without noticing and a pre-recorded voice should be spoken to person opposite side.

Please mention if can be done on both iOS and android or anyone or none.

Thanks for Help.

Comment: iOS doesn't allow intercepting of phone calls by a 3rd party application. This might be able to be done on Android but not iOS so the answer to your question is no, you cannot do that, neither with Flutter nor with a native iOS app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both operating systems will not allow you to do that. 1st point is somehow possible in Android but 2nd one is almost impossible to do in both platforms.
Apple **dont allows** to *intercept most of their system APIs* by some 3rd party